# VLOOKUP and HLOOKUP with hyperlink in excel

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vlookup

How can I use Hlookup and vlookup with hyperlink formula in excel sheet.

My VlookUP function

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Lookup1, 2, FALSE)
 ("idarubicin hydrochloride"[tiab] OR "57852-57-0"[rn] OR "idamycin"[tiab])
```

and my HlookUP function

```
=HLOOKUP(C1,Lookup2, 2,FALSE)
 ("triamcinolone acetonide"[tiab])
```

works fine.

I need to create dynamic hyperlink using above two lookups which should be like

```
  http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=("idarubicin hydrochloride"[tiab] OR "57852-57-0"[rn] OR "idamycin"[tiab])AND("triamcinolone acetonide"[tiab])
```

I am able to use one VLOOKUP in hyperlink

```
=HYPERLINK("http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term="&LEFT(VLOOKUP(A2,Lookup1,2,FALSE),200),B2)
```

But I also need to include HLOOKUP, how can I include that

Comment: You can only have one hyperlink in a cell. It doesn't matter whether you ar using the [HYPERLINK function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HYPERLINK-function-333C7CE6-C5AE-4164-9C47-7DE9B76F577F) or the [Hyperlinks.Add method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822490.aspx).

Comment: Cant I make a dynamic hyperlink link, using two lookups?

Comment: What does it mean _its not working for me_?

Comment: The *link_location* parameter of the HYPERLINK function is just text representing a URL or URI so, yes, you can concatenate a string using text and the results from a [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) or [HLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HLOOKUP-function-f3f3b210-5dd6-4b58-9c83-b9db2c306d6a).

Comment: I get "#VALUE". When I hover over the cell,, it doesnt show me any hyperlink

Comment: Show a working URL (the one provided doesn't work) together with some sample data that shows how you are returning the web page search parameters from data on the worksheet.

Comment: when I tried =HYPERLINK("http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term="&LEFT(VLOOKUP(A2,Lookup1,2,FALSE),200),B2) It worked fine, How can I add another Hlookup in above formulas

Comment: Try using an `index match` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The resulting http link was too long and thats why it was showing me #value
The final query would be

```
=HYPERLINK("http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term="&CONCATENATE(LEFT(VLOOKUP(A2,Lookup1,2,FALSE),200),"AND",LEFT(HLOOKUP(C$1,Lookup2,2,FALSE),255)),B2)
```